# Propositional Logic: How to reason about the "empty" list?

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

Suppose $n=0$, how do this definition make sense in that case ? In this case the book states that this list of formulas $\Phi_i$ evalute to $\top$ for all valuations. But what reasoning can I use to prove this property of the empty list using Propositional Logic ?

I understand, I can't use quantifiers in Propositional Logic.

[image]

Comment: If you can't use quantifiers in Proposition Logic, why is there a "for all" in Definition 1.34?

Comment: I'm confused, indeed. But isn't quantifiers limited to another branch of logic ?

Comment: You don't use quantifier _within_ propositional logic, but you can use quantifiers when reasoning _about_ propositional logic. ${}\qquad{}$

Answer (score 2):

We say that :

> $\Gamma$ *tautologically implies* (or *logically implies* or *semantically entails*) $\varphi$ (written $\Gamma \vDash \varphi$) iff every truth assignment for the sentence symbols in $\Gamma$ and $\varphi$ that satisfies every member of $\Gamma$ also satisfies $\varphi$.

We say that :

> $\varphi$ is a *tautology* (written $\vDash \varphi$), when $\emptyset \vDash \varphi$, i.e. every truth assignment (for the sentence symbols in $\varphi$) satisfies $\varphi$.

---

In order to appreciate the first definition, we can transform it into a sort of "procedure" :

*(i)* consider a valuation $v$;

*(ii)* if $v$ does not satisfy some formula in $\Gamma$, throw it away;

*(iii)* if $v$ does, then check if it satisfy also $\varphi$.

Now it must be more evident the role of $\Gamma$ : it acts as a "filter", selecting from the set of **all** *valuations* a subset to be used for checking the satisfiability of $\varphi$.

What happens when $\Gamma = \emptyset$ ? Being empty, the emptyset cannot be used to "filter" any valuations, and thus the above "procedure" boils down to :

*(i)* consider a valuation $v$;

*(ii)* check if it satisfy $\varphi$,

and this is exactly what the second definition amounts to.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're asking, "When do we have '$\emptyset\models\psi$'?"

If this is the case, the answer is: only when $\psi$ is a tautology. By definition, $\emptyset\models\psi$ iff every valuation making every formula in $\emptyset$ true, makes $\psi$ true. However, every valuation *at all* makes every formula in $\emptyset$ true, since there aren't any. So $\emptyset\models\psi$ if and only if $\psi$ is true under every valuation.

---

You mention that propositional logic doesn't use quantifiers; I think this is an instance of confusing the theory and the metatheory. When we reason *about* propositional logic, we do so in a much more complicated logical system, where - among other things - we are allowed to use quantifiers. Definitions like that of "$\models$" take place in this metatheory.

Comment: Thanks, but how do you prove "However, every valuation at all makes every formula in ∅ true, since there aren't any." without using "common" sense in a formal way?

Comment: Via a stronger logical system - e.g., first-order logic. The axioms for first order logic let us prove statements like this very easily. In general, what you are quite rightly observing here is that propositional logic isn't powerful enough to reason about itself. Stronger logics, like first order logic, are! *CAVEAT: The truth value of the previous sentence depends on what you mean by the word "are." Obviously there's limits. But there are many good senses in which first-order logic can be described by first-order logic.*

Comment: Now, you might ask, "But how do we justify the axioms?" The answer to this is, you can't get something from nothing - at some stage we do need to appeal to common sense, intuition, or whatever you want to call it in order to come up with some basic axioms and rules of inference. You might find this unsatisfying, and that's very fair. The issue of how to justify axioms and rules of inference is a deep philosophical one, which I'm not going to touch with a ten-foot pole.